# How to assign the functor via an interface to a function object?

Tags: c++, function, interface, polymorphism

I have an interface and a class that implements it. Consider following code:

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Interface {
public:
  virtual bool operator()() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Interface {
public:
  bool operator()() override {
    //some code here
    return true;
  };
};

int main() {

  Derived d;

  function<bool()> bar = d; //compiles without any errors

  Interface* i = new Derived();

  function<bool()> foo = *i; //does not work

  return 0;
}
```

The compiler returns error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'Interface' to 'std::function'. How can I assign the functor via an interface to a function object?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the suggestions. Using std::bind helped but I still have a problem when I want to pass a parameter in the operator() function. See the following code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Interface {
public:
  virtual bool operator()(unsigned int) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Interface {
public:
  bool operator()(unsigned int count) override {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      cout << "Hello World \n";
    }
    return true;
  };
};

bool doSomething(function<bool(unsigned int)> const& predicate) {

  if (predicate(5)) {
    return true;
  }
};

int main() {

  Derived d;

  doSomething(d); //works

  Interface* i = new Derived();

  doSomething(std::bind(&Interface::operator(), i)); //does not compile

  return 0;
}
```

I get the compiler error C2664:

> 'bool doSomething(const std::function &)': cannot
>   convert argument 1 from 'std::_Binder' to 'const
>   std::function &'

Any ideas?

Comment: out of curiosity: why do you want to use `std::function` when you already have your `Interface` ? `std::function` is doing a lot more than what you need here

Comment: `std::function` is trying to slice your object while copying it, and is stopped by the fact that `Interface` is abstract and cannot exist on its own.

Comment: `function<bool()> foo = [=] { return (*i)(); };`

Comment: `function<bool()> foo = std::bind(&Interface::operator(), i);`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I have a different class that expects a function object and i wanted to provide it via a functor of a class.

Answer (score 2):

The line `function<bool()> foo = *i;` is attempting to slice your `Derived` instance to a `Instance` (due to assignment operator on `std::function`), which can't happen because it's an [abstract class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class). You can use a lambda to bind your function:

```
function<bool()> bar = [&]() { d(); };
```

Having read your comment:

> I have a different class that expects a function object and i wanted to provide it via a functor of a class

You could do something like this:

```
void Foo::Bar(Instance &instance)
{
    // Be careful of lifetime issues, depending on lifetime of stored function
    std::function<bool ()> func = [&]() { instance(); };
    // Do something with func
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**After question edit.**

```
class Interface {
public:
    virtual bool operator()(unsigned int) = 0;
};
```

`operator()` now has one parameter of type `unsigned int`, but a functional object returned by `std::bind` takes zero.

Possible solutions:

```
doSomething(std::bind(&Interface::operator(), i, std::placeholders::_1));
// or
doSomething([=](auto... args) { return (*i)(args...); });
// or
doSomething([=](auto... args) { return std::invoke(*i, args...); });
```

Comment: imho the edit should have been a seperate question. The one that was asked originally already has an answer